# Change Banner Size in header - JA Teline IV template

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, fix-my-code

I am using JA Teline IV template and Joomla 3.3.3. I want to change the header banner size to 728x90. But when I add a banner with this size, it is cut of at the right side. How can I solve that?

I am not familiar with programming. I want to put my AdSense banner.

Here you can see the template with a 460px banner: http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#ja_teline_iv

Comment: Have you a link to your website? Probably a css issue, use FireBug to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS code to your custom.css file:

```
.custom.ads {
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
  float: right;
}
```

The `custom.css` file is located in: templates/YOURTEMPLATE/css . If you don't see the file, create new file then open that file to add CSS to style for your template.

[image: JoomlArt banner resize]